# Extracting and Comparing Data below an Image in a OpenOffice Spreadsheet

Tags: xml, image, vb6, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

Its been weeks when Im trying to figure out how to deal with Images inside spreadsheet of OpenOffice Calc using VB6. I tried many different solutions like OOo programming but still I didnt get the output I needed. This time I tried to change the way of doing it. So before I ask my Question I want to explain the scenario.

1.The user has an .ods file (the file is created in **OpenOffice Calc**)

2.I have a program that will import the said .ods file

This is what it looks like

[image]

The above scenario is on the user side now the next scenario is on the program side.

3.After browsing the .ods the program will create a copy in `Replicate File` Folder

4.After copying the file it will convert .ods into .zip and here is the output of it.

[image]

Please pay attention on the `Picture Folder` and `content.xml` because this two are the basis of my question.

5.Next is the program will unzip the file and transfer it in `Extracted File` and here what looks like.

[image]

Now here it is. as what you see on the above image the image has compost of a name like `BunchOfNumbersAndLetters.jpg` and upon investigating or looking the `content.xml` the `BunchOfNumbersAndLetters.jpg` is linked name of the image. Now here is my goal. Here is the example part of `xml`.

[image]

Now here is my question how can I extract the data from this kind of `xml` and use that data to retreive it? I hope someone help me with this one.

I have this code but its not working

```
Dim doc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
   Dim success As Boolean

   success = doc.Load(App.Path & "\Extracted File\content.xml")
   If success = False Then
      MsgBox doc.parseError.reason
   Else
      Dim nodeList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList

      Set nodeList = doc.selectNodes("Node Area")

      If Not nodeList Is Nothing Then
         Dim node As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
         Dim name As String
         Dim value As String

         For Each node In nodeList
            ' Could also do node.attributes.getNamedItem("name").text
            name = node.selectSingleNode("@name").Text
            value = node.selectSingleNode("@value").Text
            MsgBox name
            MsgBox value
         Next node
      End If
   End If
```

I try to get a new code but it has an error.

```
Dim oDoc AS DOMDocument
Dim oNode AS IXMLDOMNode
Set oDoc = new DOMDocument40
oDoc.Load "content.xml"

Set oNode = oDoc.SelectSingleNode("text:p")

MsgBox oNode.Text
```

The error is undeclared namespace :text

Comment: This is probably the best way to solve this problem.  However your XML parsing code doesn't look very good.  What is "/Report/Categories/Category" supposed to find?  I do not see anything like that in `content.xml`.  It should grab the filename from the `xlink:href` attribute and the title from the `text:p` tag.

Comment: Yes sir your right the `xlink:href` and `text:p` but how can I achieve that sir?>

Comment: Have you looked at any VB6 XML parsing tutorials?

Comment: @JimK its nice to meet you again this is the new way of getting my output based on our last discussion sorry for creating a new post that is related to this.

Comment: Well in this case it makes sense to add another question.  However two questions is enough -- one for the XML parsing approach and one for the other approach where we tried using the UNO API.  The other questions should be closed.

Comment: Noted sir I will close the other one and by the way sir I edited my post and see my new code with an error

Comment: If I compare the 2 codes looks like the first one is better since where getting the image inside the calc. file rather than this one that needs to browse/duplicate/zip/unzip/ then get the image and the xml file. Well who knows the longer version might give us the right solution. Its hard for me to do this because both applications are too old based on what applications using right now. I tried to code the first in excel and I took only one day rather than this that i get nothing until now.